# С# Winforms & proxy

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, proxy

Всем привет. Пишу небольшой простенький почтовый клиент для нужд одного из научных порталов в моем университете, который будет уметь массово с интервалом отправлять письма своим клиентам (которые публикуются) по базе мыл. В общем, эдакий спамер. Всё ок, всё работает (когда прямое обычное соединение к Интернету, где осуществлялась отладка - т.е. мой ноут  )
В самой редакции прямого соединения нет. Доступ к Интернету у них через прокси, который им выделил Университет. Я слабо понимаю всю суть прокси, но как-то так: на некоторых ПК у них прописан айпишник и порт в Internet Explorer и доступ есть везде (скайп поднимается, все браузеры пашут норм). На некоторых машинах (ноуты) в Хроме стоит плагин SwitchySharp. Там вбит айпишник и порт прокси. Когда ноут в редакции - вкл режим прокси, когда не в редакции - обычный режим (direct connection). Например, скайп лежал бы тут, если бы не прописали в нем настройки прокси, ну а так все норм (потому что прописали). Это был экскурс в тему))
В общем проблема вот в чем: мой пресловутый клиент ничего не отправляет ни в том, ни в другом случае вследствие того, что он как бы не видит подключение к Интернету ни в том (настройка через ИЕ), ни в другом случае (плагин в Хроме, ну тут-то он вряд ли бы и заработал).
Либо нужно как-то правильно машины настроить (как?), либо как это прописать в коде С# в самой программе (подключение через прокси), чтоб программа работала именно через прокси-соединение?
Очень буду благодарен вам за помощь!

upd: Либо какая есть утилита, которая "перебьет" все соединения на пк и выставит на прокси (чтоб и скайп не настраивать, ну вследствие и программулина заработает)? ОС Win7

upd2:
вот кусок кода, отвечающий за отправку:

```
MailAddress fromAddr = new MailAddress(from,nameOfCompany);
MailAddress toAddr = new MailAddress(Convert.ToString(address));
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromAddr, toAddr);
mail.Subject = subject.Text;
mail.Body = body.Text;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtp, port);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Если прокси обычный, то соединяетесь с ним, вместо целевого сервера и шлете в сокет текст `CONNECT ip:port\n`. По идее должен вас соединить. Если прокси socks - то ищете какую нибудь библиотечку для работы с socks, хотя там протокол то же не особо сложный

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Как реализовать первый вариант? Можно подробнее? Как это будет кодом?

Comment: Ну а вы как HELO шлете ? вот точно так же перед HELO пишете CONNECT и ждете немного. надо посмотреть, может connect что нибудь ответит а может просто установит соединение и будет молчать

Comment: Хотя чуть сложнее http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt

Comment: Я просто на C# не в курсе как. но обычно открывают сокет и шлют текст. Раз сами не шлете - значит используете какую то библиотечку для этого. вот надо что бы эта библиотечка поддерживала прокси тогда. посмотрите ее параметры, может можно передать

Comment: @Mike в основном сообщении показал кусок, где отправка.. та читал на msdn - не могу найти.. Может, какой-то класс есть ещё, а какой - не нагуглю.. поэтому я и тут :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844835/sending-mail-through-http-proxy

Comment: Я правда не понял как оно работает. Вот еще http://www.sql.ru/forum/643890/kak-pravilno-propisat-lokalnyy-proksi-server-dlya-smtp  собственно гугл по запросу "C# SmtpClient proxy" это повыдавал

Answer (score 1):

Могу что-то путать, но вроде как для отправки почты по SMTP клиенту нужен прямой доступ к 25-ому порту SMTP сервера. А такого доступа в вашем случае скорее всег нет (т.к. прокси) 
Варианты поиска решения:

п1: Узнать стоят ли у кого в редакции почтовые клиенты на компьютерах? Если да, загляните в настройки... и просто повторите их в своём коде

п2: Если локальных почтовых клиентов ни у кого нет- нужно уточнить есть ли у вашего прокси сервера свой SMTP-сервер который ретранслирует весь SMTP трафик во вне. Если да то [в этом примере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844835/sending-mail-through-http-proxy) как раз проиллюстрирован вариант подключения к серверу SMTP на прокси.

п3: Если подобную информацию получить не удаётся то тут начнутся танцы с бубном. Т.е. надо будет подробно изучить как с локальных машин уходят письма на почтовые сервера при отправке через локальные почтовые клиенты.Т.е. установить на одну из машин почтовый клиент, настроить его и посылать письма. (далее см п1) Если локальные клиенты не работают- либо трясти админов отвечающих за прокси сервер чтоб настроили (и далее п1), либо попробовать другие методы разведки сетевых путей (трассировка, снифинг трафика и т.п.) По результатам повторить это в коде.

п4:Если у прокси-сервера нет своего SMTP то можно попробовать поднять свой локальный и настроить его таким образом чтобы он ретранслировал почту через прокси. И соответственно указывать адрес локального сервера в коде

Comment: Спасибо! Очень хорошо разъяснили ситуацию! Если не ошибаюсь, у них стоит the bat на некоторых машинах. В течение часа загляну туда и гляну, каковы настройки на исходящую почту. После этого позвольте отписаться здесь в комментариях и проконсультироваться, если возникнут проблемы.

Comment: у них есть свое мыло на поддомене универа, в the bat прописан сервак/порт: pop3.(доменное имя) и порт 110.
Также в настройках смтп прописаны свои параметры. Т.е. получается, чтобы работала моя программулина я должен использовать эти настройки SMTP? Но тогда ведь я смогу работать лишь только с их внутренним ящиком от универа? а, например, с гугловским ящиком - не смогу, т.к. смтп другой и не будет соединяться, как и прежде..?!

Comment: А вы задайте админам прокси сервера вопрос о возможности настройки mail-клиента на не их почту. (яндекс, гугл, ect..)

Comment: Вообще скорее всего на их SMTP стоит переадресация на какой-то внешний сервак где они арендуют доменное имя. Это может быть как провайдер предоставляющий университету услуги связи с интернетом так и кто-то из "гигантов" типа гугла. В первом случае всё печально. А во втором есть вероятность что как-то можно организовать работу с другими ящиками у того же поставщика услуг.